# Vuejs | how to watch window.property change?

Tags: vue.js

I'm actually struggling trying to watch an object for tracking window.gtmDataObject. On the interaction of website new object are pushed to the array window.gtmDataObject. I'm trying to watch eachtime this global variable is updated with new objects. I've tried computed properties also watcher but without success.

```
 computed: {
    gtmDataObject () {
        return window.gtmDataObject
    }
},
```

Any clue, or solutions ?

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: @KickButtowski i've updated the description with code

Answer (score 0):

For the Vue2 project, there is no interface for the proxy export by Vue, you may use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), which Vue2 is also powered by it.

```js
// your Vue root vm
const app = new Vue({...});

Object.defineProperties(window, {
    gtmDataObject: {
        value: 'string',
        writable: true
    },
    gtmDataObject: {
        get: function() {
            return this.gtmDataObject;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this.gtmDataObject = val;
            app.$root.$emit('gtmDataObject-updated', val);
        }
    }
});
```

then in your Vue component:

```js
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('gtmDataObject-updated', value => {
        // do something you want
    });
}
```

---

But I recommend you use `Vuex`(for Vue2) or `Pinia`(for Vue3) to manage your global variables instead of setting a `window` property